# Trombone - meaning of "do not clip notes"

Tags: articulation, trombone

I'm studying with the Alessi & Bowman version of Arban's method for trombone and euphonium.

Quite often, for instance when studying slurs, grace notes and arpeggios, one advice is to not *clip* a note. Not being a native English speaker, I've trouble understanding this term. Does anyone have an explanation of what might be meant here ?

[image: Instructions for studies 61–69]

[image: Instructions for studies 37–54]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To "clip" in this context means to "cut short".

With brass instruments, this can especially mean not to use the tongue to suddenly cut off the air flow. Rather, the air flow should be allowed to stop "naturally" by simply not blowing.